# Turning a second order phase transition into a first order phase transition by coupling constant

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

In general, a second-order Landau functional has the form

$$F_0 [\eta] = \frac{1}{2}t\eta^2+u\eta^4$$

where $\eta$ is the order parameter and $u > 0$. As far as I know, first-order Landau functionals have a similar expression, only a term $\propto \eta^3$. However, I'm told that a functional of the form

$$F[\eta, \epsilon] = \frac{1}{2}t\eta^2+u\eta^4 +\lambda \epsilon \eta^2+ \frac{1}{2}k\epsilon^2$$

(where $\lambda$ is a coupling constant and $k$ is a constante as well) can, by adjusting $\lambda$, represent a first-order transition.

**My questions**

- In what conditions does this represent a 1st-order phase transition?
- Is it possible to attain these conditions without differentiating our expression? If so, how?